# How to add request validation errors to ModelStateDictionary in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, request-validation

Investigating the security of a system I'm building with ASP.NET MVC 2 led me to discover the request validation feature of ASP.NET - a very neat feature, indeed. But obviously I don't just want to present the users with the Yellow Screen of Death when they enter data with HTML in, so I'm out to find a better solution.

My idea is to find all the fields that have invalid data and add them to the `ModelStateDictionary` before invoking the action such that they automatically appear in the UI as error messages. After googling this a bit it appears that no one have implemented this before which I find puzzling since it seems so obvious. Does anyone here have a suggestion on how to do this? My own idea is to supply a custom `ControllerActionInvoker` to the controller, as described [here](http://lostintangent.com/2008/07/03/aspnet-mvc-controlleractioninvoker-part-1/), that somehow checks for this and modifies the `ModelStateDictionary` but I'm stuck on how to do this last bit.

Just catching `HttpRequestValidationException` exceptions does not seem a useful approach since it does not actually contain all the information I need.

I've answered the question myself but I'd still be very interested to hear of any solutions which are more elegant/robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked a bit at how MVC does the model binding I've come up with a solution myself. I extend the `Controller` class with a custom implementation that overrides the `Execute` method like so:

```
public abstract class ExtendedController : Controller
{      
    protected override void Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        ActionInvoker = new ExtendedActionInvoker(ModelState);
        ValidateRequest = false;
        base.Execute(requestContext);
    }
}
```

For me to control when request validation occurs I've added the following to the `web.config`:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

The meat of the action happens in the custom implementation of the `ControllerActionInvoker` class:

```
public class ExtendedActionInvoker : ControllerActionInvoker
{
    private ModelStateDictionary _modelState;
    private const string _requestValidationErrorKey = "RequestValidationError";

    public ExtendedActionInvoker(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        _modelState = modelState;
    }

    protected override ActionDescriptor FindAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, ControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, string actionName)
    {
        var action = base.FindAction(controllerContext, controllerDescriptor, actionName);
        controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.ValidateInput();

        return action;
    }

    protected override object GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)
    {
        try
        {
            return base.GetParameterValue(controllerContext, parameterDescriptor);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestValidationException)
        {
            var fieldName = parameterDescriptor.ParameterName;
            _modelState.AddModelError(fieldName, ModelRes.Shared.ValidationRequestErrorMessage);
            _modelState.AddModelError(_requestValidationErrorKey, ModelRes.Shared.ValidationRequestErrorMessage);

            var parameterType = parameterDescriptor.ParameterType;

            if (parameterType.IsPrimitive || parameterType == typeof(string))
            {
                return GetValueFromInput(parameterDescriptor.ParameterName, parameterType, controllerContext);
            }

            var complexActionParameter = Activator.CreateInstance(parameterType);
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(complexActionParameter))
            {
                object propertyValue = GetValueFromInput(descriptor.Name, descriptor.PropertyType, controllerContext);
                if (propertyValue != null)
                {
                    descriptor.SetValue(complexActionParameter, propertyValue);
                }
            }
            return complexActionParameter;
        }
    }

    private object GetValueFromInput(string parameterName, Type parameterType, ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        object propertyValue;
        controllerContext.RouteData.Values.TryGetValue(parameterName, out propertyValue);
        if (propertyValue == null)
        {
            propertyValue = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Params[parameterName];
        }

        if (propertyValue == null)
            return null;
        else
            return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(parameterType).ConvertFrom(propertyValue);
    }
}
```

What this does is to perform request validation after the action has been found. This will not immediate cause an error if the request is invalid but when `GetParameterValue` is called it will throw an exception. To avoid this I override this method and wrap the base call in a try-catch. If an exception is caught I basically re-implement the model binding (I make no promises about the quality of this code) and add an error to the `ModelStateDictionary` object for the value.

As a bonus, as I wanted to return an error in a standard format for my ajax methods I also added a custom implementation of the `InvokeActionMethod`.

```
protected override ActionResult InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
    if (_modelState.ContainsKey(_requestValidationErrorKey))
    {
        var errorResult = new ErrorResult(_modelState[_requestValidationErrorKey].Errors[0].ErrorMessage, _modelState);

        var type = controllerContext.Controller.GetType();
        var methods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
        if (methods.Where(m => m.Name == actionDescriptor.ActionName).First().ReturnType == typeof(JsonResult))
            return (controllerContext.Controller as ExtendedControllerBase).GetJson(errorResult);
    }

    return base.InvokeActionMethod(controllerContext, actionDescriptor, parameters);
}
```